# Impedance matching on FPGA IO

Tags: impedance-matching, artix-series-fpga

I have a few questions related to impedance matching when designing a PCB board for an FPGA. I am Using Artix-7 XC7A200T-1FBG 484C. If have read this  http://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/user_guides/ug471_7Series_SelectIO.pdf 
and 
http://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/user_guides/ug483_7Series_PCB.pdf

The document says impedance matching depends on drive strength. I am using default drive strength. Can anyone guide me if there is a best known impedance match for 12mA?  And how to perform that impedance matching.

Comment: You linked two large manuals. Could you point to the specific pages that are relevant for your question?

Comment: yes page 44 of 
http://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/user_guides/ug483_7Series_PCB.pdf
page 13-20 of 
http://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/user_guides/ug471_7Series_SelectIO.pdf

Answer (score 1):

Drive strength and output impedance are only weakly related.

Reducing drive strength is used to reduce rise times and therefore reduce overshoot and ringing when used with mismatched transmission lines. This is adequate for 'short' lines, or with 'slow' edges.

Controlling the output impedance by DCI is used to accurately match transmission lines. This can be used for any line, and is essential for high speed serial transmission.

All outputs will have some inherent uncontrolled finite output impedance. In general, higher drive strength goes with lower inherent output impedance.

According to the first document, series 7 Xilinx FPGAs have DCI, digitally controllable output impedance. This controls the output cell to have an output impedance equal to an external reference resistor (or half that in another option). If you want an accurate output impedance, this is the mode to use.

According to the second document (page 44), LVCMOS outputs set to 6mA drive strength have *a crude approximation* to a 50ohm output impedance. Later references say 6 to 8mA for the same impedance. From that you can infer that a 12mA drive strength output is likely to have a lower inherent output impedance than 50ohms, but not by how much lower. You can also see that if you want a better match to a specific impedance, you should use DCI and not drive strength control.

Comment: Thank you so much for you response. Okay about Using DCI isn't it ONLY available on HP banks? (As mentioned in http://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/user_guides/ug471_7Series_SelectIO.pdf page 19,20). 
 I am using HR IO Bank. Still I should use DCI? Would it work?

Comment: 2.  Also according to Page 13 of http://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/user_guides/ug471_7Series_SelectIO.pdf 
 HP bank supports only upto 1.8V. 
So if I dont use DCI and try to set impedance using drive strength. Is there a way to measure/check FPGA's IO impedance? 
 Thank you.